# apt-get update error: no hash entry and Package: header?

Tags: apt, package-management

When I try to update software on 11.10 I get the following errors:

```
W: GPG error: http://repository.akirad.net akirad-oneiric InRelease: File /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/repository.akirad.net_dists_akirad-oneiric_InRelease doesn't start with a clearsigned message
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/repository.akirad.net_dists_akirad-oneiric_main_binary-i386_Packages Encountered a section with no Package: header
W: Failed to fetch http://repository.akirad.net/dists/akirad-oneiric/main/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/repository.akirad.net_dists_akirad-oneiric_main_i18n_Index
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Updating software through the GUI also gives me errors about downloading packages, but they are a lot less verbose.

I never had any trouble performing updates in the last version of Ubuntu.

What do I need to do to fix this error?

Comment: Close your question with the check mark if the answer is enough to understand this fault, regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are just unlucky, the ppl behind that repo forgot to renew they domain registration!

(I'm guessing that 'repository.akirad.net' is the correct address and you didn't made any mistakes there, but 'akirad.net' is closed!)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I removed that repository and it fixed the problem. I wonder what software that used to be...

Comment: No idea, that was why I was looking for the packages but the domain was not more :S